# PHP code to display block based on list (text) field

Tags: entities, blocks

Drupal 7. I'm trying to display a block using the "Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE" feature. The field is a single value list (text) named **field_display_block** so all I want to do is determine if field_display_block is set to "1".

I'm sure there are a couple of ways to do this. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Les Z

Answer (score 3):

With the following script you can check the value and return true. I've added my comments before each line.

```
// First check if the current page is a node
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
 // Then, check if it is your content type
 if ($node->type == 'your_content_type') {
   // Get the value of your field
   $display_block = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_display_block');
   // If the field's value is equal to 1, then return true
   if ($display_block[0]['value'] == '1') {
     return TRUE;
   }
  }
}
```